# Adding text on mouseover in D3 Tree

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I have added text to a D3 Tree before, but now that I am creating nodes at runtime, the text on mouseover doesn't work.  I know the function is being called because I print to console on mouseover which works as expected.  I'm guessing that with the transitions of the moving nodes and static text changes how I can add additional text.  Code shown at:

[jsfiddle.net/7L3A7/](http://jsfiddle.net/7L3A7/)

The code I had previously used to add text on mouseover is as follows:

```
node.on("mouseover", function (d) {
                var g = d3.select(this); // The node
                // The class is used to remove the additional text later
                var info = g.insert('text')
                        .attr("x", function (d) {
                            return (d.parent.px);
                        })
                        .attr("y", function (d) {
                            return (d.parent.py);
                        })
                        .text(function (d) {
                            return "asdfadfg";
                        });

                console.log("adfhadfh");
            });
```

but this doesn't appear to work now that the nodes are added at runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've made a couple of changes in this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/henbox/bGR8N/1/

**Firstly**, you were adding the `<text>` element to `<circle>` SVG element so your HTML looked like:

```
<circle class="node" r="4" cx="235" cy="480">
    <text x="235" y="240">Info on FOO</text>
</circle>
```

Instead you should add both the text and the SVG shape to a separate `g` element, using something like:

```
var gelement = node.enter().append("g");
gelement.append("circle")...
```

So your HTML looks like:

```
<g>
    <circle class="node" r="4" cx="268.57142857142856" cy="480"></circle>
    <text x="268.57142857142856" y="480">Info on FOO</text>
</g>
```

You'll also need to take that new structure into account when creating the links using `link.enter().insert("path", ".g.node")` instead of just `link.enter().insert("path", ".node")`

**Secondly**, this change means that the mouseover text appears at the *parent* level, which I assume isn't what you wanted, so I changed `x` to be accessed from `d.x` rather than `(d.parent.px)`, and did the same for `y`

The remaining obvious issue is that `<text>` is not removed on mouseout

Comment: Thank you so much, I especially appreciate the explanation!

Comment: I doubt, you'll see this, but now when I add nodes, some are overlapped by the links (is there an easy fix?), is that because we have the nodes grouped now?

Comment: Can you give a bit more detail? I don't see any overlapping even with several hundred nodes. I don't think the grouping should make a difference here

Comment: I fixed the issue, i had to change link.enter().insert("path", ".g.node") to link.enter().insert("path", "g"), as I posted here: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24743594/forcing-links-to-draw-under-nodes